# Sorting Server Side with AJAX, headers not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got a problem:

Not all headers work to sort the table, and some of them partially work, I.E.: **`Marca`** and **`Modelo`** work perfectly but **`idTipoDeVehiculo`** just works once and **`idAuto`** and **`FechaDeLanzamiento`** never work.

Okay, this is my index.php:

[index.php](https://plnkr.co/edit/h6AViCKofmr11vKz3fGF?p=info)

And this is the order-column.php:

[order-column.php](https://plnkr.co/edit/MkOnu6EnHFLK2x45aBlS?p=info)

Here is the AJAX, but I don't think the problem lies in there:

```
function orderColumn(column_name, column_order) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "order-column.php",
    data: 'orderby=' + column_name + '&order=' + column_order,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#demo-order-list').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

**I'm not allowed to use any plugins and forced to use AJAX.**

Anyways, I tried everything and I'm completely lost, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: As you are getting all rows - there don't seem to be any conditions -  you might as well sort in javascript, that would make the interaction a lot more responsive / faster.

Comment: if you console.log() data in the success function, do you see the table data?

Comment: Why not to use some plugin like [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)?

Comment: use `&&` not `and`

Comment: Jeroen: I'm forced to make the sorting server side, not client side.
ProEvilz: Yes, this what comes out: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jVvc2fPkaMO282R1lnsQ?p=catalogue).
camelsWriteInCamelCase: I'm not allowed to use plugins unfortunately.

Comment: Deckerz: where are you referring to exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you did not declared your variables. See this:

```
if($orderBy == "idAuto" and $order == "desc") {
    $idAutoNextOrder = "asc";
}
```

If the `$orderBy` not `idAuto` or `$order` is not desc, your `$idAutoNextOrder` won't created but later you reference to it.

```
$idAutoNextOrder = "desc"; //<----Init here
if($orderBy == "idAuto" and $order == "desc") {
    //change if need
    $idAutoNextOrder = "asc";
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh, the names were wronggggggggggg. How could I miss it!
Thank you so so much!